# paypal do direct payment philippines

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

hi i live in the philippines and im having a problem using paypal **do direct payment** using different currency code
when i tried my code using **USD** it works fine but when i changed the currency to **PHP** for philippines peso it gives an error of **10755 Unsupported Currency**. im only using sandbox account.

my question is on what factors can i get an error of unsupported currency code? 
is it by the type of credit card the user have? is it by where us the merchant registered? 
or the biling info and country code the user supply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paypal does not support PHP currency for direct payments and express checkout.

https://cms.paypal.com/mx/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_currency_codes

Comment: thanks.. i miss that so it means that i need to convert the currency to USD first for the transaction to complete?

Comment: Actually it's supporting PHP currency you just need to make sure that you define the currency code when setting the express checkout details through SetExpressCheckout.